# how to play a sound in android

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I am creating a scramble word game application which plays two sounds depending on the success or failure. On the success of the guess, the game plays one sound file. On the failure of the guess, the game plays another sound file. I 've written the following code

```
public void checkWord()
{
    MediaPlayer mp;
    if(abcd.equals(etGuessedWord.getText().toString()))
    {
        WordLibrary.setMyInt(WordLibrary.getMyInt() + 10);
        tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(WordLibrary.getMyInt()));

        new AlertDialog.Builder(JumbledWords.this).setMessage("Awesome!!!") 
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            wordIdx = (wordIdx + 1) % getSize();
            sWord = getScrambledWord(word_list[wordIdx]);
            tvScrambledWord.setText(sWord);
            abcd = word_list[wordIdx];
            ++word_array_length;
            etGuessedWord.setText("");

            if(word_array_length >= word_list.length)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(JumbledWords.this).setMessage("Level Complete!!! ")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

                @Override 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    start = 0;
                    finish();           
                } 
                }).create().show();     
            }


        } 
        }).create().show();
        **mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap);**
        mp.start();

    }
    else
    {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(JumbledWords.this).setMessage("Wrong. Try Again")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            etGuessedWord.setText("");
        } 
        }).create().show(); 
        **mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oop);**
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

The code mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.oop) gives exception. I have done my my best to avoid exception such as IOException. The application halts in between and gives a "Force Close". What is wrong with the code? Is there any other way of programming to load the sound? Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the context you are using to create the object, "this" is an activity context and under certain conditions, does not contain references to raw objects.  I had the same problem which I solved by using the application context instead of the activity context.

Try changing your create code to the following:

Context appContext = getApplicationContext();

mp = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, resid);

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually using `SoundPool` for playing sounds, it's more comfortable for me. You can check this link: [Sound Pool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the sound file you're trying to play has the proper extension (e.g. `clap.wav`).

Comment: The sound file is in the res/raw folder. It is determining through R.raw.clap

Comment: I meant the file name should be `clap.wav`, not just `clap` (assuming it's in wav format, of course).